# Identify an anime series with combining robots

Tags: story-identification, robots, anime

It is a mecha anime. I believe 4 or 5 robots combine into 1 giant robot. There are 2 male and 3 female pilots. one of the guys, the red head, sister has disappeared. the head of the team is this guy that gives these grand speeches about everything... it is hinted in the story that hes either immortal or a time traveler because some people found a few paintings with his likeness throughout history. Also there were 2 seasons that I know of. Had a friend suggest Aquarion but this came out before Aquarion did.

Anyway I have been wracking my brain and I cannot remember and help would be awesome... thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Gravion?

It was a horrible Gonzo anime, but I'm pretty sure this one had a "god-like" protag, combining mechas, and two seasons.

The main character, a redhead, is looking for his sister:

> The protagonist is Eiji Shigure, a young man who infiltrates Sandman's
>   St. Germain Castle **in search of his missing older sister Ayaka**

[image: Eiji]

The billionaire benefactor (Klein Sandman) who creates the mecha is immortal:

> **he takes the name and appearance of the actual Klein Sandman, an 18th-century aristocrat.** To provide himself the means to prepare for
>   the Zeravire, **Sandman genetically suppresses his own G-Factor,
>   giving him immortality** and turning his hair purple from its original
>   blond.

The mecha is formed from five units, with three female pilots and two male pilots:

[image: Team]

Sources: [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/Gravion)
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravion)

Comment: I'd upvote you, if it wasn't for the editorializing.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds an awful lot like Guren-legan, it too featured a redhead female and a man called Kamina who made the most outrageous speaches that despite sounding non-sensical often inspired the whole troupe. Kamina wore spicey glasses, and had a brother called Simon.

On of the speeches went along the lines of:

> Don't believe in yourself. Believe in me who believes in you Believing in you believing in yourself!

and also:

> DO YOU KNOW WHO I AM?!

Mostly everything else you mention fits with some minor details tweaking.